# Question on Hoffman and Kunze's proof of the Cayley-Hamilton theorem: why is $ \det (xI-A) =x^2-\mathrm{Tr}(A)*x+\det(A) $

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

At one point, in the proof of the Cayley-Hamilton theorem the authors say that $$\det (xI-A) =x^2-\mathrm{Tr}(A)*x+\det(A)$$ for any $n\times n$ matrix that represents a linear operator, $I$ being the identity matrix. Should not that determinant be a polynomial of degree $n$? In that case how can it equal a polynomial of degree 2?

Comment: Most probably, they're looking at $n=2$. Do you have a reference to look at? (Page number, scan, &c)

Comment: Second edition page 195, just after the point where he takes the case n>2

Comment: Try reading it carefully. They might be just looking at the case $n=2$ to develop some idea to work out the general case.

Comment: I'm absolutely sure that it computes the polynomial $ f = x^2−Tr(A)∗x+det(A) $ when he takes the case n=2, then for n>2 he says that $ det B = f(T) $.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've the book ($2$nd edition) in front of me: if you mean at page 203, where it talks of "...where $\,f\,$ is the characteristic polynomial..." , 6 lines up they wrote "When $\,n=2\,$ ...", so this is only for $\,2\times 2\,$ matrices.

Comment: Second edition page 195, just after the point where he takes the case n>2.

Comment: Yes, I made a mistake: it is in page 195, not 203, and no: the formula $$f=x^2-(trace A)x+\det A$$ is one line immediately before they write "For the case $\,n>2 \,$, it is also clear..."

Comment: But that makes no sense, he defines the symbol f, then when he takes the case n>2 he talks about f as it was already defined. Was he trying to say that "it is also clear that det(B) is a polynomial in T"?

Comment: This is the whole parraph: When n = 2
Bii = 6ijT - AjJ.
and
B = T - Ad -&uI
[ - A121 T - AnzI 1
det B = (T - Ad) (T - Ad) - AlsAd
= T2 - (An + A&” + (An& - Add
= f(T)
where f is the characteristic polynomial:
f = x2 - (trace A)z + det A.
For the case n > 2, it is also clear that....

Comment: As you can see, the whole thing except the very last few words is under the assumption $\,n=2\,$ and **there** they define $\,f\,$ as the char. polynomial. *not* aterweards, when the $\,n>2\,$ case begins!

Comment: Could it be that your edition has some messed up lines? For me it is very clear...

Comment: I think you forgot the $'s. Was he trying to say that "it is also clear that det(B) is a polynomial in T"?

Comment: No, I did not forget them: I copied and pasted directly from the book and you can follow it with *your* book.

Comment: And yes, they write $\,\det(B)=f(T)\,$ and then they pass to explain that $\,f\,$ is the char. pol.... **all** the time talking of the case $\,n=2\,$ !

Comment: Read it in your book, there it is very clear! After the part where they write " When$\,n=2\,$" . then write down a $\,2\times 2\,$ matrix $\,B\,$ and then they write $\,\det B\,$ ...etc.

Comment: Ok, so they define f as the characteristic poly.(that's the key). Sorry for the trouble and thanks!

Comment: Well, not actually definining but talking of it as something already known: it is very easy, for someone with some background in these matter, to see that the char. pol. of a $\,2\times 2\,$ matrix indeed has the form that they show in the book.